# How to make main window wait until a newly opened window closes in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, window, wait

I am new to WPF as well as C#, please bear with me.

I have a main window which opens up a new window. Now this new window is a prompt whether or not to overwrite a file, and the main window accesses a public variable in the new window to check for the prompt's result.

But I can't get the main window processing to wait until the new window closes.

```
 Window1 Win = new Window1();
 Win.Show();

 if (Win.pr_res == 1)
 {
      abc.Text = "File to be overwritten";
      File.Delete(_destination);
      Start();
 }
 else
 {
      abc.Text = "Operation Aborted";
 }
```

I tried adding a while loop checking another public boolean in the main window, but that just hangs the entire program.

```
 while(!_closecheck);
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of `Show` -

```
Win.ShowDialog();
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) -

> Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is
>   closed.

Answer (score 7):

Use ShowDialog() method as it Opens a window and returns only when the newly opened window is closed.

syntax

```
Win.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 4):

Although `ShowDialog` works fine, you may set `MainWindow.IsEnabled = false` if you don't like that modal window. Sometimes it's useful to see the main window.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using the .Show() property for openning/showing the window, use .ShowDialog() instead :)

Comment: This sounds like a repeat of [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20540195) and also [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20540316).