# C# Wait for another opened window to close before executing the rest of the function

Tags: c#, wpf

I had created 2 WPF window.

For Window 1:

```
//Get IC Detail First
COAKeyInAccountICCanvas COAKeyInAccountCanvas = new COAKeyInAccountICCanvas(this, _PrinterIsOn);
COAKeyInAccountCanvas.Topmost = true;
COAKeyInAccountCanvas.Show();

if(CheckCOAKeyInICStatus.checkCOAKeyInAccountICStatus == true)
{
    //Check User Ownership
    checkCOAOwner.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; // let user to choose whether is owner or representer
}
else
{
    accountNumber = "";
    checkCOAOwner.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    GetAccountCanvas.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Initially, the `COAKeyinAccountCanvas` window will do a checking and update the `CheckCOAKeyInICStatus.checkCOAKeyInAccountICStatus` to be either "**false**" or "**true**".

How can i unhold the if-else statement function to be executed before the `COAKeyInAccountCanvas` window had finished all the function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make main window wait until a newly opened window closes in C# WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540139/how-to-make-main-window-wait-until-a-newly-opened-window-closes-in-c-sharp-wpf)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use:

```
COAKeyInAccountCanvas.ShowDialog();
```

instead:

```
COAKeyInAccountCanvas.Show();
```

Comment: May i know what is the different between this 2?

Comment: show a modal form or a modeless form. see the MSDN reference

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-US/library/39wcs2dh(VS.80).aspx

Comment: If i used show dialog, mean that if my coakeyinaccountcanvas had successfully updated the status, only it will proceed to the bottm if-else statement right?

Comment: it means that the next code to the ShowDialog call will execute once the coakeyinaccountcanvas has closed.

Comment: The Show function shows the form in a non modal form. This means that you can click on the parent form.

ShowDialog shows the form modally, meaning you cannot go to the parent form

Comment: Okay thanks, it seem working fine now. And i marked it as answer :) Have a good day ahead.